# Direction, Position of User in Room when photo taking

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-location

I am new to iOS programming, so I hope anyone of you can help me with this problem :)

The iOS app I am working at enables the user to take photos and save the image with custom metadata (date&time, latitude,longtitude etc)to the device. 
Only the camera function (taking photos and save it) is working by now and I am trying to save the exifdata (gps,date and time) to the image.
But the reason why I am writing this thread is, because I have no idea how to assign the direction of the camera and the position of the user in a room to the image?

So to get a better understanding of my problem, imagine that you are standing in a room and you want to take pictures of all items in this room. Lets say the room usually has 4 walls, so everytime you take a picture of a wall, you have to save your position in the room, where you're taking the picture and your direction, because later it should be possible to say which wall you were facing (and to mark your position on a floorplan for example).
There already exists an app called **Solocator**, which provides the functions I need. But I want to implement these functions in my app and have to know the idea behind them :)

So first of all I need to know the distance between my position and all four walls in the room (or the distance to a corner point(?) between to walls)? How? With CLLocationDistance?

I would really appreciate any ideas you might have! 
Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about the fact you cannot get accurate GPS location INSIDE a building?

Comment: But if you are looking fr orientation, use the compass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)Youre right, there could be problems with GPS satellite locks indoors. So for the direction I just save my compassorientation, right? But what about the position of the user inside that room?